# html: create pop-up box same as when required field is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a form with three questions and I want to show the questions in a particular order. Each question has to be answered in the textbox. I have the following example:

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a8suL3bc/)

```js
var imageIndex = 0;
var images = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/June_odd-eyed-cat.jpg",
    "https://www.aaha.org/contentassets/f557d057200b4d7197d67acce3ea725f/image9iii.png",
    "https://cdn3-www.cattime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/persian-cats-and-kittens/persian-cat-breed-pictures-1.jpg"    
     ];

function next() { 
    //document.getElementById('grade').value = '';

    var grade = $("#grade").val();

    if(grade == '') {
      alert("Please give a grade");
    }
    
    else {
      imageIndex = (imageIndex+1) % (images.length);    
      $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
      
      // need to record the value

      // set to empty
      $('#grade').val(""); 
    }
    
    if(imageIndex == images.length - 1) {
      $("#next").attr('style', 'display: none');
      $("#submit").attr('style', 'display: inline');
    }
}

   $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#image").attr('src', images[0]);
     $("#next").on("click", next);
    });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>

<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!--<p>image ${image_url}</p>-->
          <img src="" class="img-fluid" id="image" height="auto" width="700" align="center">
      </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <label>Please grade with anything:</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input id = "grade" type="text" max-length="25" value="" required></input>

</fieldset>


<p><input type='button' id='next' value='Next' style="display: inline"/></p>

<p><input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' style="display: none"/></p>




</form>

</body>

</html>
```

However, for the first two questions, I can only have the alert when no answer is typed into the textbox. For the last question, I can get the pop-up box that says 'Please fill out this field' next to the textbox.

It turns out the `required` attribute in textbox only restricts the last question. How can I make the first two questions having the identical style of the pop-up box as the third question when the answer is missing?

Additional/side question: it looks like after the form is submitted, only the answer to the last question is being recorded. How can I record all the answers?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The third question's button is type **submit** while the first and second questions button is type **button**. Seems that `required` attribute works only with `submit` in any other case you should write a custom validation function.

Comment: "*Only the last answer submitted*" - when you submit a `<form>` it sends all the `<inputs>` - you only have 1 input so you only get one submitted.  You're changing the use of the input via js but not storing that change anywhere (you even have this with `// need to record the value`).   You can add new `<input>`s (maybe type=hidden or style=display:none) each time so they are all posted or you can create your own POST `$.post(...)` to send all the data you've recorded in your JS and don't use the `form` post.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for the suggestion. I did have only 1 input field, but I have three inputs entered into that field. Is there any built-in solution to use with `form` post?

Comment: Consider `var x = 1;` `x=2;` `x=3;` - how would you send those 3 values over given you only have 1 integer variable?  That's what you're asking.  There's no "built-in" way to put 3 values into 1 variable.  You use 3 variables or you use a different type of value, such as an array (which you populate from your input)